# sigma-algebra generated by a stochastic process

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a stochastic process and $\tau$ a random time. Does the following hold:

$$ \sigma (X_1, \dots, X_\tau) \subset \sigma( X_1, X_2, \dots) \ ?$$

Clearly, $\sigma (X_1, \dots, X_n, \tau ) \not\subset \sigma(X_1,X_2, \dots) $, as the $\tau$ here definitely gives additional information. But what about the above case? Is it obviously true?

Comment: Do you assume that the random time $\tau$ is measurable wrt the canonical filtration of $(X_n)_n$? If not, then there is no reason to expect that the inclusion holds.

Comment: @saz I assume that $\tau$ is $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots)$-measurable. So, it is not a stopping time but still somehow connected to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\mathcal{F} := \sigma(X_i; i \geq 1)$. If $\tau$ is random time which is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, then $\{\tau=i\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $i$. By definition,

$$X_{\tau} = \sum_{i \geq 1} X_i 1_{\{\tau=i\}}.$$

The finite sum

$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i 1_{\{\tau=i\}}$$

is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable since $X_i$ and $1_{\{\tau=i\}}$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for each $i$. Hence, the limit

$$X_{\tau} = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i 1_{\{\tau=i\}}$$

is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable (as pointwise limit of $\mathcal{F}$-measurable functions).

This shows that $X_{\tau}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable for any $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random time $\tau$. Hence,

$$\sigma(X_{\tau}; \text{$\tau$ is an $\mathcal{F}$-msb'le random time}) \subseteq \mathcal{F}=\sigma(X_i; i \geq 1).$$ (The converse inclusion is trivial because we can choose $\tau=i$ for fixed $i \geq 1$.)